# IBM Access Client Solutions shared credentials do not work

Tags: ibm-midrange, credentials

I am trying to automate a data transfer profile from our IBM i (AS400) machine. I want this to be able to run unattended so i tried the following per instructions:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar acsbundle.jar  /PLUGIN=logon /SYSTEM=xxxxxxx /USERID=xxxxx /PASSWORD=xxxx

java -jar acsbundle.jar /PLUGIN=download /userid=xxxxx c:\BI_DATA\DATA_DEF\GR_F0101.dtfx
```

It seems that the credentials are saved in the cache but the transfer command asks for credentials:

[image]

The .DTFX transfer profile is set to **"Shared Credentials"** option in connection tab

P.S : Dropped it also in developerworks . [LINK HERE](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ac0b6c37-ae13-4320-829e-4b3db961b014)

Comment: I posted a link to the [midrange-l mailing list](http://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l]); since I know some of the IBM'ers responsible for ACS hang out there.

Comment: There is a `DTBATCH` plugin that looks just like `DOWNLOAD`, except it claims to work in batch. Maybe the `DOWNLOAD` plugin is for interactive?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Same things are happening with DTBATCH also.

Comment: @Charles Any news btw from the list?

Comment: Sorry, nothing on the list.  Though a couple of the answers posted seem to be from users of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the CLDownload plugin?? Quoted from the Getting Started page, "The plugin enables the user to run a simple download of an entire file from the command line."

```
/PLUGIN=cldownload /system=<system>
                          [/userid=<userid>]
                          {/hostfile=<library/filename> | /sql="statement"}
                          {/clientfile=<path><filename>.<extension> | /display}
```

Comment: Here is a link to that page for those who are unsure. The plugins are described in section 9 of the document: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/solutions/GettingStarted_en.html

Comment: It doesn't fit my needs as i want to specify other things other that the SQL statement. and this i can do it only with the DTFX file specification

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to have a system configuration created in the product with the shared credential option. Otherwise, the /PLUGIN=logon action will not know to store the password in the shared credentials cache.

One could also investigate the use of a _netrc file (see Edit->Preferences), but on Windows, a plaintext file with your password stored in it could be a security issue.

An aside worth noting, specifying the password on the command line is a security issue because the command line args can be seen by any user of the workstation. So, if you're running on a shared system (Windows Server), be aware.

Comment: Tried it , added a system configuration with shared credentials and did not work. It still asks for password

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the following settings to make the cached credentials work. Go to Communication-Configure-Connection-Advanced

There change the password prompting in "user default user name to prompt once for each system"
Add userID(xxxxx) in the Userid field.

I then ran command /PLUGIN=logon /SYSTEM=xxxxxxx /USERID=xxxxx /PASSWORD=xxxx
after that the cached credentials worked for me. SO make sure to use "user default user name to prompt once for each system" instead of "use shared credentials"

Answer (score 0):

Anyone get this to work? I am struggling to automate using SSIS and the IBM Client Access solutions. No matter which option I do, it always prompts for a user name and PW on the first run. When I run it through Execute Process Task in SSIS on a SQL server, I can't plug in the User name and password on the first run.

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/automating-acs-data-transfer

From the link above I do exactly as instructed, but it still prompts for user name and PW even though they've already been entered on the first line:

"To prevent the transfer from prompting for a user ID, use two consecutive commands using the logon and data transfer plug-ins:"

C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\acslaunch_win-64.exe /plugin=logon /system=myibmi /userid=myprofile /password=mypassword
C:\Users\Public\IBM\ClientSolutions\Start_Programs\Windows_x86-64\acslaunch_win-64.exe /plugin=download C:\testacs.dtfx

Comment: I understand and appreciate your struggle, and I wish I could give you a working answer. But I can't. What I can say is: (1) What you've posted here is not an answer. It's kind of a comment, but too big to be a comment. So, if it's not an answer and too big to be a comment, what can you do? Unfortunately, not much on Stack Overflow. Upvote this question and leave a proper (short) comment on the question. That's about it. But (2) you can join and post to the [midrange mailing list](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l). You may have better luck there.